# What is the smallest prime number factor of 2020^8 + 1?

Tags: number-theory

I was unable to reduce $2020^8 + 1$ and I believe that it is impossible indeed to reduce it into smaller numbers using algebra ($a^8 + 1$ cannot be factorized without involving non-integer numbers. So can anyone suggest a solution for this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127554/discussion-on-question-by-kristianachwan26-what-is-the-smallest-prime-number-fac).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are finding the smallest prime such that $2020^8 = -1 \pmod p$. Squaring both sides, $2020^{16} = 1 \pmod p$.

By Fermat's little theorem, $2020^{17-1} = 1 \pmod {17}$ and $2020$ is not divisible by $17$. We still need to verify that $2020^8 \equiv -1 \pmod {17}$ and not $1$ (both values square to $1$). As $2020 \equiv 320 \equiv -20 \equiv -3 \pmod {17}$, $(-3)^8 \equiv (81)^2 \equiv (-4)^2 \equiv -1 \pmod {17}$.

Hence the smallest prime factor is $17$.

Comment: Yeah, too bad Sophie Germain doesn't help here :-)

Comment: I posted in a hurry because the solution was so obvious (it was interspersed in the comments). Everyone was too busy arguing in the comments ;)

Comment: No, it isn't appropriate.

Comment: Especially for future readers, the comments only distract from what answers the question and what can help the OP. Going off on some argument about: "oh, how would you find the solution if the numbers were different" is hardly relevant to the conversation and I expect the thread to be cleaned up.

Comment: This is very helpful :) Can you suggest a good article for learning this number theory such as Fermat's little theorem you mentioned above? Thankyou :)

Comment: See the page on [AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Number_theory).

Comment: thankyou for your suggestions :)

Comment: You can do this because $8$ doesn’t have any non-trivial odd factors, so we know $8\mid p-1.$ This wouldn’t work for $a^6+1.$

Comment: Ah yes, which I totally missed by focusing on the modular arithmetic. The OP's initial attempt of trying to factorise $a^8+1$ did have some merit.

Answer (score 0):

$2020 = 4*5*101$. Write $101 = 102 - 1$, since $17*6=102$

So, $[~[4*5*(102-1)]^8 + 1]$, use Binomial Theorem and you get

$$17.[some~integer] + (17+3)^8 + 1$$

$$17.[some~integer] + 17[some~integer] + 3^8 + 1$$

$$17.[some~integer] + 17[some~integer] + [(17*5)-4]^2 + 1$$

$$17.[some~integer] + 17[some~integer] + 17[some~integer] + 4^2 + 1$$

Comment: The question is how do you know $17$ is the smallest prime factor in the first place? Assuming that you're using Fermat's little theorem, it doesn't seem natural to continue this way.

Comment: The rest is quite cleverly done without using modular arithmetic, such as the fact that $(4 \cdot 5 \cdot (-1))^8 + 1 = (-20)^8 + 1 = 20^8 + 1 = (17 + 3)^8 + 1$ plus some multiple of $17$.

Comment: TBH when I saw the question, already people started mentioning 17 as answer, so I tried out with it. Else it would be difficult to figure the initial step, if Fermat's little theorem is not known [I don't know it yet]. But I think there is a fair possibility to guess for 17 looking at prime factors of 2020 & what follows will be the proof for the initial guess.

Comment: Thank you for your response anw :)

Comment: If you expand $(102-1)^8$, the only term that isn't a multiple of $7$ is $(-1)^8$.

Comment: Yes I know that. Okay so you just expanded for ease of other readers I guess